# HiddenField isn't a WebControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, inheritance

Why does `System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField` inherit `System.Web.UI.Control` instead of  `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl`? It seems really illogical placement if not the fact that hidden fields are used in web pages.. What's the reason it was designed like this?

It makes things quite annoying when you can't do things like `WebControl x = new HiddenField();`

Comment: Note that `WebControl` also inherits from `Control`

Comment: Indeed, but you can't cast a `HiddenField` into a `WebControl`. (And yes, I'm refactoring :])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary difference between `UI.Control` and `UI.WebControls.WebControl` is that `WebControl` is meant to serve as a base class for a component that has a UI.  Since a hidden field never displays anything to the user (it's hidden, after all), `UI.Control` is a more suitable base class.

Comment: But we all know that you can display hidden fields when you disable CSS.. But +1 for logic.

Comment: I believe the HiddenField renders as <input type='hidden'/>, which would still be hidden even if CSS was disabled.  If it was rendered as a different HTML element with 'display:none;' CSS, then yes, it would still display.  But I'm pretty sure that's not the case.

Comment: During refactoring I noticed most of my changes were around WebControls that had Width/Heights being set - so it does stand to reason that having such properties makes no sense for a field that shouldn't/won't be displayed.